# Django i18n is not detecting texts inside the for loop

Tags: django, internationalization, django-i18n

I couldn't understand why the i18n is not detecting the data in my loop:

`{% trans service.title %}`

anyone who can help!?
Thanks in advance!

```
{% load i18n %}

{% for service in services %}
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="service bg-white">
                        <div class="img-block">
                            <img alt="" class="service-img img-fluid"
                                src="{{service.img.url}}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="service-feature">
                            <h4 class="feature-text text-center">
                                {% trans service.title %}
                            </h4>
                            <p>{{service.desc}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I tried several different ways such:

`{% translate service.title %}` no reactions

`{{ service.title|trans }}` no reactions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your content is coming from the database and is dynamic, traditional string-based translation won't work as intended.

Django doesn't have built-in support for database content translation, but there are third-party packages available that can help. One of the most popular is `django-modeltranslation`. Here's how to use it:

1. **Install `django-modeltranslation`**:

```bash
pip install django-modeltranslation
```

2. **Add it to your `INSTALLED_APPS`**:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'modeltranslation',
]
```

3. **Set Up Translations in your Model**:
   Suppose you have a model like this:

```py
class Service(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    desc = models.TextField()
    ...
```

To add translations for the `title` and `desc` fields, you'd create a `translation.py` in the same app directory:

```py
from modeltranslation.translator import register, TranslationOptions
from .models import Service

@register(Service)
class ServiceTranslationOptions(TranslationOptions):
    fields = ('title', 'desc')
```

4. **Migrate the database**:
   After setting up translations for your model, you need to create and apply migrations to add columns for each language you're supporting:

```bash
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

5. **Use in Templates**:
   In your template, when the appropriate language is active, the translated version of the fields will automatically be used. So you can simply do:

```
{{ service.title }}
{{ service.desc }}
```

6. **Admin Integration**:
   `django-modeltranslation` also supports integration with the Django Admin, providing tabs for each language where you can input translated content.

Remember to always read the documentation of third-party packages and test them to make sure they work as expected and satisfy your requirements.